# formating/indenting stored text data in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to format text data stored in my sqlite file, so when queried it will return with formatted data, more specifically indents.

I've read that this should be done in the front end application but it seems that would would be taxing to format hundreds of different, nonuniform entries. (these entries do share the same column value in the table though)

I have bullets in almost all of my entries but cannot indent them to nest properly.

is there anyway execute a sql statement to the column to add indent behavior like so

- alksdjf ;lkasjdfl kajsl;dk fja;lsk djfal;ksjdfl;aksjd fl;kasjdfslkdfjals;kdjf;laksjdflkajs;dlkfja;lskjdfl;aksjdflkasjd;lfkjasl;kdfjl;

the text lines up with each other past the bullet

Comment: The database will store whatever you tell it to. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: So i am copying and pasting from documents that are like 100 pages long, obviously copying and pasting from these documents doesn't keep the formatting 100 percent, i know i can go in and do UPDATE and REPLACE to add indentations before the bulllets, but it doesn't quite fix the problem that when the line goes under the bullet it wont indent with it... check update

Comment: _"doesn't keep the formatting 100 percent"_ This doesn't make sense unless your source material isn't plain text. Are you cutting text from MS Word docs or something?

Comment: Yes the source material isn't plain text, its a pdf file converted into plain text, which isn't helpful for keeping all the formatting... so i am cutting and pasting from at plain text file its just the conversion from .pdf to .txt doesn't keep all the formatting i need

Comment: Sorry i'm not asking for how to store it formatted but to format already inputed data using a sql statement of some sort.. and i know that this sounds fruitless

Comment: _"sounds fruitless"_ Heh yep. The amount of effort it would take to come up with SQL queries to correctly text-adjust the formatting loss caused by the PDF to text conversion would be more than the effort required to simply store the already-formatted PDF docs.

Comment: If you're very lucky, those PDF docs will have been generated from marked-up text (like via md2pdf) and you might be able to acquire those source docs and run a different generator to output plain text (like via md2txt) from them.

Comment: Yeah but i have to break the pdf files down and organize it for the application to work, which would require the database. and breaking down a pdf into hundreds of separate files would create huge file sizes (the database is stored locally to phone app)

Comment: I guess i should of used this website http://pdf2md.morethan.io/ .  Well back to data entry :(